# Java - Programatically taking excel and open office spreadsheets to tab delimited files

Tags: java, excel, cross-platform, spreadsheet, extract

I'm querying the community on a solution to the following problem...

I need a way to automate the creation of tab delimited extractions (.txt or .tsv extentions). This needs to be accomplished for .xls, .xlsx, and open office spreadsheets. The automation needs to be independent of microsoft specific solutions ruling out say VBScripting, Apache POI (which is troubling already with .xls and .xlsx differences), etc.. One thing I was thinking was looking at extensions to determine the library that should be used for extraction. However, I'm trying to gauge what others might do or if someone has found a platform independent solution already.

Any suggestions or comments on how to do this would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your concerns with Apache POI?

Comment: Well POI is microsoft specific is it not? My research has indicated that this is the case. I've used POI to read from excel files but I also need a library that can handle say Open Office Calc for extraction. Can POI handle this format?

Comment: I see. Maybe you'll have to convert from Open Office to Microsoft, then Microsoft via POI to tsv. These links may help - http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html, http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/word-2007-docx-converter-oxygenoffice.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-version-differences) can't help with the open office formats, unconverted. It is rather excellent with the BIFF and OOXML Excel and Word formats, however, and has a programmatic API. You could do conversions for open office to work with it, or only use OfficeWriter for the ms-specific formats as you mentioned.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who created the latest version.